# What are all of the keyboard shortcuts for OneNote 2013 equation editor?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote-2013

I love using OneNote 2013 for my note taking, but whenever the professor starts writing equations I start to get behind by having to use the equation editor and manually entering in equations, symbols, etc,.  I'd like to speed up my equation editing by using the keyboard shortcuts/quick formatting features built in.  What are these shortcuts?

---

Example shortcuts that I already know:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> will start a new equation editor
- `x_i` + <kbd>space</kbd> = x<sub>i</sub>
- `x^i` + <kbd>space</kbd> = x<sup>i</sup>
- if I type in:

  `(<equation>)/(<equation>)` + <kbd>space</kbd>

  I get a nicely formatted equation like so:

  ```
  <equation>
  ----------
  <equation>
  ```

These are just a few.  I'm looking for an exhaustive list of these features.

---

<sup>Note: I'm not looking for [keyboard shortcuts for just OneNote](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-OneNote-2013-65dc79fa-de36-4ca0-9a6e-dfe7f3452ff8).  I'm specifically talking about the equation editor.</sup>

Comment: There is a full list at Microsoft.com: https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-OneNote-2013-65dc79fa-de36-4ca0-9a6e-dfe7f3452ff8

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 those aren't what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for the Equation Editor shortcuts.  Slightly different

Comment: the Alt+= is a keyboard shortcut (on that list). I'm pretty sure the others you've mentioned are auto-corrections/auto-formats, not shortcuts. Similar to when you type a `:)` (and then hit space) in Outlook and it replaces it with happy face. So I'm thinking you're probably looking for a list of those auto-corrections/formatters, not really 'keyboard shortcuts'. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes... and I didn't know what else to call them.... and no.... I believe that some of the functions are going to be a shortcut (continuing with your example `Ctrl+B` to make text bold in any office document).  I'm just looking for anything within the scope of the Equation Editor.

Comment: They are laballed as AutoCorrection, or AutoFormat in the options of most/all Office applications. Not sure about OneNote specifically off hand though, as I don't have it installed. :)  In Word (2013, I think 2010 is the same) they're under File -> Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options...  Anything like that in your OneNote?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes!  That's exactly what I'm looking for.  However this doesn't include all of the things (i.e. the division autoformatting).  This does however include all of the symbols which is half of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 16):

## UPDATE DEC 2020

The equation editor was updated in Office 2018 onwards. Documentation for the new editor is here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/write-an-equation-or-formula-1d01cabc-ceb1-458d-bc70-7f9737722702

The functionality appears to largely be unaltered, so the information in this answer is likely to work, but I have not tested it. The white paper linked below is likely still relevant, though the original listing document has been removed and the link no longer works.

---

### OLD ANSWER

A few months late, but I believe [This is the document you are looking for.](http://www.iun.edu/%7Emathiho/useful/Equation%20Editor%20Shortcut%20Commands.pdf) (**LINK NOW DEAD**) As best I can tell, OneNote 2013 uses the same equation editor as Word 2007/2010.

A whitepaper on the Word 2007 equation editor key commands can be found [HERE](http://unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf) on unicode.org.

---

**TL;DR:** Symbols are basically the same as in LaTeX, as are a few simple formatting commands like `\thinsp`, `\sqrt`, etc. From there, it is pretty good at figuring out what you mean if you type it the way you would try to type it in plaintext.

---

`ALT+=` enters an equation at the cursor point.

A handful of symbols:

```
  \partial  

  \alpha        \eta       ο    \omicron       \upsilon
  \beta         \iota          \pi            \varpi
  \chi          \varphi        \theta         \omega
  \delta        \kappa         \vartheta      \xi
  \epsilon      \lambda        \rho
```

Other handy notation:

```
\sum
\int
\scriptL
```

To add extra space:

```
\hairsp  a small space  
\thinsp  a wider space
```

To add a function, type its name followed by a space:

`sin<sp>\theta` becomes sin

If a function is not recognized (like sinc), you can force apply function styling with `\funcapply`, by typing `sinc\funcapply<sp>`

Derivative ticks:

x′ `x\prime<sp>`

To do fractions, use `/`:

a/b

Parentheses are treated as a grouping character. For example, they would NOT show up in the fraction `(a+b)/c`. To get them to show, use `((a+b))/c`. Delimiters `()`, `[]`, and `{}` will automatically grow to the size of whatever is contained within them. You can pad the space within delimiters with `\phantom` and `\vphantom`.

---

The rest you will have to go read up on yourself, as Markdown doesn't support rendering LaTeX examples (AFAIK).

Comment: Can you post some of the more important shortcuts from the linked document?

Comment: SHIT!  The doc you linked was taken down!

Comment: Equation Editor 3.0 was removed some time ago, but the new equation editor seems to function mostly the same. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/write-an-equation-or-formula-1d01cabc-ceb1-458d-bc70-7f9737722702#ID0EAACAAA=Write_new_equation

Answer (score 2):

There is also a handy way to find the keyboard shortcut for most symbols that you can insert manually. Create an equation (alt+=), then go to equation tools (design) and hold your cursor above the character you want. After a few seconds, a textbox will appear telling you the name of the symbol and a keyboard shortcut, which is usually preceded by a backslack.

Press space after entering the shortcut into the equation box and onenote will convert it to the symbol.